# Example of a homomorphism from $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ with kernel $K = \{A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})| \det(A) = \pm 1\}$

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find an example of a homomorphism from $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ with kernel $K = \{A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})| \det(A) = \pm 1\}$ however it is eluding me. I can't seem to make it a homomorphism.

Comment: $f(A)=(\det A)^2$

Comment: The book I have just says $\mathbb{R^+}$ but they generally refer to the additive group by just $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathbb{R^+}$ is the multiplicative group of positive reals,
then use this function: $f(A)=|\det A|$.

If $\mathbb{R^+}$ is the additive group of the all reals,
then use this function: $f(A)=\log |\det A|$.

Comment: This is a nicer example because it does not rely on the domain being abelian.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: what happens if you square both sides of the equality that appears in the definition of $K$?

Comment: Also $\det(A)^2$ works

Comment: @ililil how is that a homomorphism?

Comment: @ililil: $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ consists of all invertible $n \times n$ real matrices; in particular, such a matrix has nonzero determinant.

Comment: @continental: that's the map I was hinting at.